# An sqlite3 error: "no column name". How to fix?

Tags: sqlite

I created a table called x.

I filled the table with values. The command .schema gives:

```
   CREATE TABLE x(id integer, title text, value integer);
```

I can print out all the data from the table.

However, when I go to do this command:

```
   SELECT value from x;
```

I get the error:

```
  "Error: no such column: score"
```

I can't figure out how to fix this.

Edit:

```
 PRAGMA table_info(movies);
```

gives
cid     name type            notn       dflt   pk

0        id integer          0           0
1      title text         0           0
2      value integer        0           0

I also used .import path x

to get data into the data. It apparently worked because I print out all the data.

Comment: Your SQL appears to work in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cd749/1)... can you provide any additional information about your schema or environment setup?

Comment: Have you ever had a `score` column in your database at some point? _(Maybe there is a caching issue going on?)_

Comment: It works now. Apparently, copy and pasting messed things up. When I typed the same thing, it worked. But when I copy and pasted the same thing, it didn't.

Comment: Maybe there were extra characters being added from the copy/paste... interesting;